# TFS Force Get programmatically via SDK

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfs-sdk

I can't figure out any way to force get a file from TFS programmatically. My current code:

> _workspace.Get(new GetRequest(serverPath, RecursionType.None, new DateVersionSpec(dateTime)), GetOptions.Overwrite);

The above code will get a specific version, but if I manually delete the file, TFS thinks its still there.  How can I use a force get for a specific version?

Answer (score 5):

To do a force get, use `GetOptions.GetAll`.  Eg:

```
workspace.Get(new GetRequest(serverPath, RecursionType.None, new DateVersionSpec(dateTime)), GetOptions.Overwrite | GetOptions.GetAll);
```

Answer (score -1):

I actually figured it out.
The problem with using GetAll is, that it gets all and I just want one specific version of a specific file.

This is what I did:

```
_controlServer.GetItems(serverPath, new DateVersionSpec(dateTime), RecursionType.None).Items[0].DownloadFile(_workspace.GetWorkingFolderForServerItem(serverPath).LocalItem);
```

Comment: Because if you call Get() then TFS will only update the file if its thinks it should. The way I mentioned above is like a force get on just one file.

Comment: That's what `GetOptions.GetAll` is for, actually.

Comment: The mechanism you propose will not update the file in your workspace - it will only download the file to disk and you will be left with a writable file conflict.

Comment: Edward, thanks for the reply. That is very true about the download() causing issues when it becomes writable.  But I believe GetOptions.GetAll will get all files, which would be a very bad thing since the other files sizes are very big.  I used Download() which returns a stream and sent the stream to the user, so in that case I wont have the issue you mentioned.

Comment: What do you mean by "all files"?  You will  only get the `ItemSpec`s specified, but it will get all of them ("force get") them, regardless of whether they're already up to date.  If you don't want all those items, pass the `ItemSpec`s you do want.

Comment: Ok, my assumption was GetAll was at a scope of the workspace, not the ItemSpec.